# C++11 method template specialization for return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, specialization

I've got following class:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  T bar() {
      cout << "Called with return type: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;

      T t = //... (some implementation here)

      return t;
  }
}
```

It's invoked in following way:

```
Foo foo;
int i = foo.bar<int>();
long l = foo.bar<long>();
```

Now i'd like to have different specialization for cases when function is invoked with `shared_ptr<T>`

```
Foo foo;
foo.bar<shared_ptr<int>>();
foo.bar<shared_ptr<long>>();
```

But of course I don't want to create full specialization for each type. Is it possible to implement such behaviour (can be trait-based if required)?

Comment: Function templates can't be partially specialized, but class templates can. Create a wrapping class template that exposes a public static member function, partially specialize the class and change the member function appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since noone proposed it yet, one can use SFINAE to distinguish between `T` and `std::shared_ptr<U>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr_impl : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr_impl<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
using is_shared_ptr = typename is_shared_ptr_impl<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type;

class Foo
{
public:    
    template <typename T>
    auto bar()
        -> typename std::enable_if<!is_shared_ptr<T>{}, T>::type
    {
        std::cout << "T is " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return {};
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto bar()
        -> typename std::enable_if<is_shared_ptr<T>{}, T>::type
    {
        using U = typename std::decay<T>::type::element_type;
        std::cout << "T is shared_ptr of " << typeid(U).name() << std::endl;
        return {};
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec26435aaa63c23f)

Comment: You don't consider cv-qualifications. What about making `is_shared_ptr` `is_shared_ptr_impl` and `is_shared_ptr` an alias template that refers to `is_shared_ptr_impl<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>`?

Comment: @Columbo how about now?

Comment: I didn't think of references. Now it's just fine.

Comment: Together with another trait which would allow to extract X from shared_ptr<X> in second version of function this looks like a very nice solution (though such trait is not part of this question, no need to specify it here)

Comment: @Daimon you don't need another trait, in *shared_ptr case* case just use `typename std::decay<T>::type::element_type`, like in update

Comment: Marking it as accepted answer as it suites my needs best way :)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot partially specialize functions. For a story on why, check out this [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

You *can* partially specialize classes though, so what you could do is:

```
template <typename T>
T bar() {
    return bar_impl<T>::apply(this);
}
```

Where:

```
template <typename T>
struct bar_impl {
    static T apply(Foo* ) {
        // whatever
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct bar_impl<std::shared_ptr<T>> {
    static std::shared_ptr<T> apply(Foo* ) {
        // whatever else
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to be solution which came to my mind after 0x499602D2 comment. Also it looks to be a bit less "hacky" than Mooing Duck's answer

Comment: @Daimon I dunno that I'd call it "hacky" necessarily. I've never seen it before - and it does offer at least two advantages over my answer: (1) all the `Foo` code is in `Foo` (2) you can access private members of `Foo` without friendship. Mine is just the more accepted/common way of doing this.

Comment: Regarding friendship. Can't I just make bar_impl an Inner class of Foo? This should create friendship automatically and still keep implementation internally?

Comment: @Daimon Unfortnately no. Specialization must appear at namespace scope.

Comment: I guess one could use à functor for that.

Answer (score 6):

There's certainly many ways to do it.  The first way that comes to my mind is simply function overloading.  Since you don't have a parameter to overload on, you'll have to make one.  I like pointers, which effectively act as a way to pass types to functions.

```
class Foo {

    //regular overload 
    template<typename T>
    T bar(T*) { //takes a pointer with an NULL value
      cout << "Called with return type: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;

      T t = //... (some implementation here)

      return t;
    }
    //shared_ptr overload - NOTE THAT T IS THE POINTEE, NOT THE SHARED_PTR
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> bar(std::shared_ptr<T>*) { //takes a pointer with an null value
      cout << "Called with return type: " << typeid(T).name() << endl;

      std::shared_ptr<T> t = //... (some implementation here)

      return t;
    }

public:
    template <typename T>
    T bar() {
        T* overloadable_pointer = 0;
        return bar(overloadable_pointer);
    }
};
```

I've never heard of anyone else using pointers to pass types around, so if you choose to do this, comment thoroughly, just to be safe.  It *is* wierd code.

It may be more intuitive to simply use a helper struct to do template specialization, which is what most people would do.  Unfortunately, if you need access to the members of `Foo` (which you presumably do), using template specialization would require you to pass all those members to the function, or friend the template helpers.  Alternatively, you could pass a type_traits specialization thing to another member, but that ends up simply being a complex version of the pointer trick above.  Many find it more normal and less confusing though, so here's that:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo_tag {};

class Foo {
    //regular overload 
    template<typename T>
    T bar(Foo_tag<T>) {
    }
    //shared_ptr overload - NOTE THAT T IS THE POINTEE, NOT THE SHARED_PTR
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> bar(Foo_tag<std::shared_ptr<T>>) {
    }

public:
    template <typename T>
    T bar() {
        return bar(Foo_tag<T>{});
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it.

Comment: Indeed, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Why "with an undefined value"? The value is 0... you just mean that it's unnamed right?

Comment: @Barry: I'm used to conservative documentation, by saying it's "undefined" I mean "DO NOT USE".  However, you're right that it's always a null pointer, so I've altered the documentation to say that, which is probably clearer anyway.

Comment: @MooingDuck Can I propose instead of doing `T* only_used_for_type_anyway = 0;` to make a `template <typename T> empty_ { };` and pass an `empty_<T>{}`? You get all the same benefits without the extra potentially confusing pointer.

Comment: @Barry: I'd intended to hint that in the last paragraph, but I've laid it out more clearly.